# Redirect stderr to file with pyinstaller

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyinstaller, stderr

I try to create an error log for my compiled python project. If I use pyinstaller without the -w flag I can see an error message at crashes with the line number where the error occured. Unfortunately the console closes directly after. For better usage I want to log these error messages in an seperate file. So I run this code infront of my main method which I found [here](https://www.mail-archive.com/pyinstaller@googlegroups.com/msg07758.html):

```
if sys.platform == "win32":
    date_time_obj = datetime.now()
    timestamp_str = date_time_obj.strftime("%d-%b-%Y_%H_%M_%S")
    filename = './Log/crash-{}.log'.format(timestamp_str)
    sys.stdout = open(filename, 'w')
    sys.stderr = sys.stdout
```

Everything works out in pycharm but when I compile it with pyinstaller only the file is created without any contents.

I tried to compile it with -w flag and without like so:

`pyinstaller main.py --name Software --log-level DEBUG --icon=resources\Icon.png 2> build.txt`

`pyinstaller main.py --name Software --log-level DEBUG -w --icon=resources\Icon.png 2> build.txt`

In both cases the log file is created with no contents although I have specific crash with an error message. Without the -w flag I can still see the error message in the console.

Comment: The file is created because you explicitly create it in your code.  It sounds like either a library you are using, or possibly elsewhere in your code sys.stderr and sys.stdout are being redirected yet again.  You should set up logging

Comment: Thank you very much for your comment. I used now the sys.excepthook to catch all uncatched exceptions and log these exceptions in my defined hook. This works aswell for windowed python executables